# C# transpose one comma separated string over another

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to transpose values from one comma separated string to another comma separated string.

Example 1

```
Input 1 : 1,19,2,20,3,30
Input 2 : ,,{0},{1},,

Output  : ,,2,20,,
```

Example 2

```
Input 1 : 1,19,2,20,3,30
Input 2 : ,,,,{0},{1}

Output  : ,,,,3,30
```

Both the input strings have some other values at the start. So if any logic where positions calculated from the end would be benefitial to me.

I actually have a list of string which contains pattern like input 2 values. And then input 1 value needs to be transposed to all the strings having pattern like input 2.

Thanks,
Rohan.

Comment: sorry I don't get what you want to achieve. What is the meaning of Input 2? Why are there braces? What is the meaning of 0 and 1?

Comment: @user287107 : thanks - but i already got the solution by Cetin Basoz

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
    TransformCustom("1,19,2,20,3,30",",,{ 0},{ 1},,")
    );

//Output: ,,2,20,,
Console.WriteLine(
TransformCustom("1,19,2,20,3,30",",,,,{ 0},{ 1}")
);

//Output: ,,,,3,30
}

private string TransformCustom(string input1, string input2)
{
    return string.Join(",",
    input1.Split(',').Zip(input2.Split(','), (i1, i2) => new {i1, i2})
        .Select(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.i2)?"":i.i1));
}
```